# Burial of ashes of a Muslim who has been cremated due to Corona Virus?

Tags: death, halal-haram

Due to the Corona Virus epidemic, Muslims in Sri Lanka are being cremated according to a gazetted law. The Ulema say the ashes can be buried. Please clarify this with valid references.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe the ashes cannot be buried?